# Why am I getting the error "*** stack smashing detected ***" while running a ZMQ publish example?

Tags: c++, stack, zeromq, stack-smash

I am running a simple ZMQ publish example on an Intel upboard. My ZMQ version is 4.2.3. The original example had a while loop, I just replaced it with a for loop. At the end of the for loop I get "stack smashed" error.

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#define within(num) (int) ((float) num * random () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))

int main () {

    //  Prepare our context and publisher
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");

    //  Initialize random number generator
    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));
    //while (1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {

        int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;

        //  Get values that will fool the boss
        zipcode     = within (100000);
        temperature = within (215) - 80;
        relhumidity = within (50) + 10;

        //  Send message to all subscribers
        zmq::message_t message(20);
        snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20 ,
            "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
        publisher.send(message);
        std::cout << "printing" << std::endl;

    usleep(10000);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with the following command :

```
 g++ -Wall pub2.cpp -o pub22 -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq
```

The following is the console output:

```
printing
printing
printing
printing
printing
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./pub22 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not able to understand the "stack smashed" error. My understanding is limited with this error, please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20` -- Why did you apply a `char *` cast here?  What error did the compiler give you without that cast?

Comment: `pub2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pub2.cpp:32:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
         snprintf (message.data(), 20 ,`
                               ^

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please refer to the compiler output above. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Does your C++ wrapper match the version of the zeromq library you are using?  I see the C++ wrapper documented in zmq 2.x, but not in 4.x so it might not be compatible.

Comment: For reference, the submitted code is modified from http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:wuserver

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for your insights. I was able to resolve the issue by updating libzmq.